# Creating SMPTE track in AVFoundation

Tags: objective-c, macos, synchronization, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I have a couple of broad questions around embedding SMPTE in what I assume should be a track of type AVMediaTypeTimecode.  The SMPTE data itself is 64 bits - followed by either 16 bits synch info for LTC, or 18 bits and 8 bit CRC for VITC.

What type of representation of SMPTE data do most consumers expect?  I.e. in FCP or similar, is it going to try to decode a 64, 80, or 90 bit frame of SMPTE info?

What endian-ness is expected for the AVFoundation track representation?

And lastly, what specific mechanism would you use to stuff the data in the track?  I.e. let's say we're talking about a file with a sample rate of 50khz, and a 25 fps non-dropframe timecode (just to make the math easy).  Let's say I cobble up a 64 or 80 or 90 bit representation of 00:00:00:01.  I would then use that first frame 2,000 times in a row, then go to by representation of 00:00:00:02.

Assuming I'm using an AVAssetWriter and stuff the AVAssetWriterInput full of CMSampleBufferRef's containing my data when it's ready?

Would appreciate any help.  The AVFoundation documentation is still a little shaky methinks.  Looks like the 32 bit quicktime interface has an almost clean way of doing this.  My application is 64 bit.